# Redirect a NodeJS server port to a subdomain or a folder (amazon ec2)

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-ec2

I've installed Apache/Linux on Amazon EC2. On one instance, I set up PHP and put the files under the directory var/www/html. On the same instance, I also installed NodeJS in a subfolder home/ec2-user/

I created a new director home/ec2-user/site, where I put a javascript file that starts a NodeJS server script (server.js) on port 8080.

Now, if the URL is http://domain.com, it directs to the PHP directory (var/www/html). And a URL http://domain.com:8080 shows the output form server.js

My question is:
Can I redirect http://domain.com:8080 to http://sub.domain.com or http://domain.com/sub ? I want the address bar on the browser will change to too. Is this possible?

Comment: This can be done with setting up proxy configuration with your webserver.  You don't mention which one you are using.  Probably it is either Apache or nginx, specific intructions will differ depending on which one you are using.

Comment: @punund, it's Apache! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved this.

First of all, set Amazon S3 and Route 53.
At Amazon S3, add a bucket "sub.domain.com." Then Static Website Hosting > Redirect all requests to another host name, then type "domain.com"
At Route 53, at a hosted zone "domain.com," create a record set "sub.domain.com." Choose type "A", then set an alias to "domain.com."
(TBH, I am not entirely sure that the steps above are necessary.)

Then change proxy setting. Make a file name "httpd-vhosts.conf." Then put it under "etc/httpd/conf.d." For detailed steps, check this answer: [Second Virtual Host's DocumentRoot is changed after launching ec2 based on customized Amazon Linux AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120113/second-virtual-hosts-documentroot-is-changed-after-launching-ec2-based-on-custo)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sub.domain.com
  ProxyPass               /       http://domain.com:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse        /       http://domain.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I restarted the EC2 instance on Amazon console. Any better solutions are welcome.